# Dashboard Scheduling not in desired format

Tags: dashboard

**I am trying to schedule a dashboard with email notification as an admin to 'others' apart from myself. I have chosen 2 public groups for emailing the dashboard schedule and succeeded but users are seeing the report as a whole(not just their team data)**

I have 2 Sales Teams :

- Chicago Sales Team &
- Detroit Sales Team & I have 3 Sales Rep in each team as well as a Sales Manager for each team.

On this basis,I created 2 public groups

- Chicago Sales Team &
- Detroit Sales Team and added Sales Managers & Reps accordingly.

I made a report called 'Opportuntites won by week' which included all Closed won opportunties for both Sales Teams.
Now, I have created a dashboard based on this report and have added 2 filters to it(for seeing the dashboard for Chicago Sales Team & Detroit Sales Team individually).This works fine without any issues.

I went ahead and scheduled the dashboard for email according to the filters I created, expecting that each member of both Sales Teams will see the data according to their team(they wont see data for the other team).Unfortunately, this did not work.

All users are seeing the report as a whole(not just their team data)
I want to create a dashboard schedule so that each person gets the scheduled dashboard with just their team data. Please advise.
[image: Scheduled Dashboard via email notification]
Also,I created a public folder and stored the dashboard it. I want to share it with the sales manager with ‘Manager Access’ and Sales Representatives with ‘Viewer Access’.I am unable to see the ‘share’ option besides my folder. Please advise.